# SyntaxError - can't assign to operator

Tags: python, syntax-error, assignment-operator

```
  File "solution.py", line 12
    Rate=8.45 and S=75 and D=tempUnit-150
        ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Entire Code:

```
tempUnit = int(input())
if tempUnit <= 50:
    Rate = 2.60 and S = 25
    print("Electricity Bill =", tempUnit*Rate + S)
elif tempUnit > 50 and tempUnit <= 100:
    Rate = 3.25 and S = 35 and D = tempUnit-50
    print("Electricity Bill =", 50*2.60+D*Rate+S)
elif tempUnit > 100 and tempUnit <= 200:
    Rate = 5.26 and S = 45 and D = tempUnit-100
    print("Electricity Bill =", 50*2.60+50*3.25+D*Rate + S)
elif tempUnit > 200:
    Rte = 8.45 and S = 75 and D = tempUnit-150
    print("Electricity Bill =", 50*2.60+50*3.25+100*5.26+D*Rte + S)
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Guys, I cannot figure out the problem here. Just a beginner at python an answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, please tag the programming language you are using

Comment: What's the purpose of the and's ?   Do you want to execute all three assignments?   You could replace the and's with semicolons.

Comment: @Mark or just have them on separate lines.

Comment: @Ishan, why do you think `Rate = 2.60 and S = 25` is the correct way to assign those values to those variables? `and` is a boolean operator, not a line separator.

Comment: I guess I am just dumb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you're trying to compare values whilst also assigning them. (python does have an operator for this called the walrus operator actually but from the looks of it, it looks like you just want to assign variables values).

```
Rte = 8.45 and S = 75 and D = tempUnit-150
```

has to be

```
Rate = 8.45
S = 75
D = tempUnit-150
```

or

```
Rate, S, D = 8.45, 75, tempUnit-150
```

Comment: It Worked. thanks, dude

Answer (score 1):

`and` is an operator that combines *expressions*.

Assignments in Python are *statements*.

Chained assignments are allowed; `a = b = c = d` is equivalent to

```
a = d
b = d
c = d
```

with assignments being performed from left to right.

Each of `a`, `b`, and `c`, though, needs to be a valid target, and while `Rate` is a valid target, expressions like `8.45 and S` and `75 and D` are not.

If you want to make three assignments, just put them in three separate statements:

```
Rate = 8.45
S = 75
D = tempUnit-150
```

---

While you can combine simple statements with a semicolon

```
Rate = 8.45; S = 75; D = tempUnit - 150
```

and use tuple (un)packing to make multiple assignments in a single statement

```
Rate, S, D = 8.45, 75, tempUnit - 150
# Equivalent to
#   t = 8.45, 75, tempUnit - 150
#   Rate, S, D = t
```

neither would be considered good style here.